# Where has the energy gone when the test charge turned away?

Tags: electrostatics

Consider an insulated ball with some charge, $q_1$, inside it. Now we make a small area over that ball uninsulated, i.e we had cut a small portion.

Now when we bring a test charge from infinity near that cutoff area the electric potential energy will increase for a positive source charge. We may say, like for a gravitational field, that the energy is lost to or provided by the gravitational field. Here the energy is provided by the electric field to the object as electric potential energy.

What will happen if we remove the test charge perpendicular to normal of the area? Here the test charge is being removed without its energy being decreased, and the energy of the electric field gets reduced which is looking impractical. I don't know where I am wrong in this approach, but I am confused with such concept of potential energy about where it is stored.

One thing to mention is that the electric field is coming out from the cut of area only. You may create it ideally. The source charge is held by some unspecified force.

Comment: in potential problems all the actions and reactions have to be taken into account. To remove something you supply energy, or to bring to a certain point, the field does not lose energy.

Comment: In one of the questions posted for gravitational potential it was given that whaen we raise an object to a particular height we give energy to the gravity i.e energy gets stored in gravitational field which then works to provide kinetic energy

Comment: It is a way of adding up the mathematics. The test particle gets the energy (kinetic) or gives up the energy in a system where the charge/gravitational_mass  is at rest.

Comment: @anna_v I would require an explanation."Gives up the energy in a system".The system would either be the object or electric field where energy is stored.If looked in depth when I considered the unspecified force it was looking as if they are providing the energy.I could guess it out more good reason for positive charge and its electric field but I found implication with negative source charge.Do you think so?

Comment: @annav In fact I think that since unspecified force on source charge is maintaining stability so it may be involved in providing the energy.

Comment: a falling object to earth acquires kinetic energy, it gets it from the energy something somebody ( Big Bang?) gave it to keep it at the high potential. A rocket projectile  loses kinetic energy the higher up it goes and it becomes potential, (i.e. it can gain it when falling back) the energy for the climb given by the explosive. .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26504/discussion-between-raul-and-anna-v).

Answer (score 1):

I think that when we enter the charge from the side, the charge will gain potential energy slowly and gradually as when we enter it we will require a counter force to the force which has acted on it to convert it into kinetic energy.

Thus there will be no such violation of conservation of energy. You are applying the force in this case, thus you are providing energy. It is somewhat like pushing a log in a tank of water at the base where you are applying the force. Please don't take it exactly like that.